# How to remove elements from a list between every x elements

Tags: python, list

I'm struggling to figure out how to remove every element between the first element if it's within 3 numbers. The expected output for some input `lst` are exemplified below.

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8]        -> [0,3,8] 
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8,15]     -> [0,3,8,15] 
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8,15,55]  -> [0,3,8,15,55]
```

The elements `15` and `15,55` survived because they do not fall in between "every 3 numbers" (i.e. between list elements having index number 0, 3, 6, 9, etc.).

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 15, 55]

for i in lst:
    if i + 3 > len(lst):
        break
    else:
        lst[::2]
    print(lst)
```

This is my attempt but it seems to output the list without removing anything.

**Output**
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 15, 55]

Sorry for the lack of effort on my original post, I have been struggling with this for most of today and I need to figure it out soon, thanks Bill for clarifying I have clarfied my attempt also.

Comment: Please clarify the requirements.

Comment: What is unclear about the requirements?

Comment: If an element is within 3 numbers of the previous one, then it should be removed from the list. 1 is within 3 numbers from zero, 2 is within 3 numbers from 1 etc.

Comment: OP didn't mean 3 elements of the list, but 3 numbers, like 45, 46, 47

Comment: I'm not really sure exactly what you are trying to do, but it seems as a problem that may be solved using a filter. You can check [this examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-in-python/)

Comment: I didn't mean 3 elements of the list, I meant 3 numbers so because we have 0 in the list I need numbers 1 and 2 removed from the list. I don't need 3 removed as that's > 3 numbers.

Comment: Why are 15,55 in the output list?

Comment: What if `lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8,15]` or `lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8]`? May you exemplify explicitly?

Comment: If the lst was lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8,15] I'd want the output to be [0,3,8,15] and if lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8] I'd want the output to be [0,3,8]

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
It seems that you're stuck on basic problem analysis and writing arithmetic comparisons.

Comment: @DaniMesejo 15 and 55 are in the output list because there are more than 3 numbers between 8 and 15 and between 15 and 55

Comment: I have edited your post based on the information given above. Please check out if it resembles your intention. Please do spend some time exemplifying the logic next time.

Comment: Thank you Bill it does, Sorry for not spending more time on the post this is a small part of an overall file and I have been making attempts on it for the full day non stop without avail, fortunately I have figured out something and your reply helped alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
[element for i, element in enumerate(lst) if (i % 3 == 0) or (i >= 3 * ((len(lst) - 1) // 3))]
```

### Example

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8]
[element for i, element in enumerate(lst) if (i % 3 == 0) or (i >= 3 * ((len(lst) - 1) // 3))]
Out[35]: [0, 3, 8]

lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8,15]
[element for i, element in enumerate(lst) if (i % 3 == 0) or (i >= 3 * ((len(lst) - 1) // 3))]
Out[37]: [0, 3, 8, 15]

lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,8,15,55]
[element for i, element in enumerate(lst) if (i % 3 == 0) or (i >= 3 * ((len(lst) - 1) // 3))]
Out[39]: [0, 3, 8, 15, 55]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to do this:

```
def function(a_list, jump=3):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(a_list), jump):
        result.append(a_list[i])
    for j in range(i+1, len(a_list)):
        result.append(a_list[j])
    return result
```